# PdfStamper changes size of MemoryStream

Tags: c#, .net, itext, memorystream

Have a PDF on disk that is 498kb.  I'm reading this into a MemoryStream which reports the size as 508978 when viewed in the debugger.  Then using a reader and stamper, the output MemoryStream has a size of 15.  When the stream is output to disk the PDF is unreadable.

```
MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream();
MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"e:\O1.pdf");           
inputStream.SetLength(fs.Length);
fs.Read(inputStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fs.Length);
inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);


PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;


AcroFields fields = reader.AcroFields;
foreach (String key in fields.Fields.Keys)
{
if (String.Equals(key, @"ReportID")) { stamper.AcroFields.SetField(@"ReportID", "Fred Bloggs");   }
}

stamper.Close();
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])outputStream.ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(@"e:\O2.pdf", bytes);
```

Comment: 1) The source of `ConvertFileToStream()` is missing. 2) You compute the length of the output stream before doing anything with the stamper; look at the length after stamping and closing the stamper; you may need `stamper.CloseStream = false`.

Comment: Taking into account your edit: Yes, your code definitively misses a `stamper.Close()` call or a `using` construct implicitly causing Close to be called. As you lateron try to use `outputStream` as a stream, you need to set `stamper.CloseStream = false` before that.

Comment: @mkl - Not understanding you here.  You say I'm missing a stamper.Close() which I get, however then you say I need a stamper.CloseStream=false before that.  Is this Java syntax as it does not exist in C#.

Comment: Sorry. No, it's not Java, it's .Net only, but the CloseStream property is not directly in the PdfStamper but in its associated writer; thus, you will want to do `stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false`...

Answer (score 3):

Your code snippet is incomplete, which makes it hard to answer your question.

You make people guess your question.

**First guess:**

You have a PDF of 10 KB, when reading it with `PdfReader`, you suddenly use 100 KB. You are surprised. How can this be?

The answer is simple: the PDF of 10 KB is compressed. When `PdfReader` starts working with it, it creates objects (requiring memory) and it decompresses data (requires more memory).

**Second guess:**

You have a `PdfReader` object and you use it to create a `PdfStamper` object. You forget to close the stamper. Suddenly you have a very small file of which PDF viewer tell you: this isn't a real PDF. How come?

You've made a mistake that many people who don't read the documentation make. The file you're manipulating with `PdfStamper` isn't fully written until you close the stamper.

**Third guess:**

You have a `PdfReader` object and you use it to create a `PdfStamper` object. You don't do anything with the stamper, you just close it. You're surprised the resulting PDF has a different size than the original one.

- The size is smaller: iText sometimes throws away unused object, and it reorders objects in different ways. This is typical for PDF libraries.
- The size is bigger: even if you didn't add anything, file size can grow, for instance when the original document is fully compressed (PDF 1.5 and higher). By default, `PdfStamper` won't create a compressed xref-stream (unless you instruct PdfStamper to compress the xref).

If none of these answers apply, I suggest that you rephrase your question. If not, you'll risk that moderators close it.

Comment: Where do I close the stamper?  It must be before I try to write from the stream, anywhere else makes no sense.

Comment: I assume the question is rhetorical as the question contains the answer.

Comment: If I close the stamper then I get a runtime about the outputStream being closed.  I also tried closing the reader (r.Close();) but this makes no difference - if I close the stamper I get a runtime and if I don't then the PDF file is 1kb and unreadable.  Appreciate this is 100% pilot error so any help would be greatly received.

Comment: "You don't do anything with the stamper,".  Sorry, I just snipped out the code that used the stamper as I know it worked.  It just loops thru the acrofields and stamps real data into them.

Comment: You corrected the code after I wrote my answer ;-) When I see your code, I stumble over choices I don't understand: why do you create the PDF in memory before writing it to a file; if you have a reason, why aren't you using MemoryStream.ToArray,... These choices are outside the scope of iText; these are pure C# design choices. This makes that I can't answer your question. In cases like this, I always suggest using Occam's Razor to cut away everything that is irrelevant and to end up with a pure iText question. Now your code is too convoluted. There are too many places where it can go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm don't need to write a file at all, it's just easier whilst testing to see if the output is correct.  I will actually be storing the resultant PDF in a Byte[] in the database.  My problem remains though that if I close the stamper I get a runtime error whilst trying to write the file using FileStream, if I don;t close the stamper I just get an empty/unreadable PDF on disk.  I will distil the code down completely and post back.  The problem is not with the stamper it's my use of it.

Comment: I have updated the code above which now works, although I had to convert the outputStream to a Byte[] in order for the file O2.PDF to be readable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Glad you now have a working solution!